# Tool for manually labelling images

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I have some blobs on a uniform background. I want a tool such that, when I click on an individual blob, it can detect its boundaries from the background, and paint it white. The blobs have distinct boundaries, and are brighter than the background. Then, once I am done with all the blobs, I want to click on the background, and paint it black, i.e. everything that hasn't been labeled as a blob should turn black.

What Ubuntu software would you recommend?

Comment: Where do you have these blobs and on what background? What do you really want to achieve? i.e. instead of having us help with what you think is the solution, tell what you really want to do and we may come up with another solution.

Comment: The background is grey, these are white-ish cells photographed with a microscope. I am trying to create training data for a convolutional neural network.